# Repeat word a random number of times

Tags: python

I want to to have a word repeated for a random number of times, the range that the value can be taken from is determined by two numbers the users enter, which are then multiplied to determine the range.

For example, if you choose 4,2,  those two digits are then multiplied to determine a range of 1-8, in whatever word you entered could be repeated 1-8 times.

My issue is that is seems like the code checks out fundamentally but obviously there's something I'm missing because it only ever comes back with the word repeated once!

```
import math
import random
import word2number 
n = int(input("Please enter a number:"))
b = int(input("Please enter a number:"))
word = input('Please enter a word:')
range_amount = n*b

for number_of_words in random.choices(range (range_amount)):
    print (word)
```

Result:

```
Please enter a number:11
Please enter a number:3
Please enter a word:glizzy
glizzy
```

Answer (score 2):

The solution would look something like this:

```
import random

n = int(input("Please enter a number:"))
b = int(input("Please enter a number:"))
word = input('Please enter a word:')
range_amount = n*b

for number_of_words in range(random.randint(1, range_amount)):
    print (word)
```

`randint(1, range_amount)` will get an integer between 1 and range_amount, then with `range()` you will iterate that amount of times.

`random.choices()` just chooses 1 item of your list, that is why you got only 1 word printed

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `range()` of a `randint`, this `randint` genarated between 0 and `range_amount`

```
for number_of_words in range(random.randint(0,range_amount)):
    print(word)
```

getting

```
Please enter a number:3
Please enter a number:2
Please enter a word:apple
apple
apple
apple
apple
apple
apple
```

Answer (score 0):

random.choices returns a list of item selected from the given list. In your case, it returns a list with a single item. Then, your for loop iterates for one time because your list has one item, and therefore it always prints the given word single time.

Try this

```
import math
import random

n = int(input("Please enter a number:"))
b = int(input("Please enter a number:"))
word = input('Please enter a word:')
range_amount = n*b

# generate a sequence of number using range function by passing first item from the list returned by random.choices
for number_of_words in range(random.choices(range (range_amount))[0]):
    print (word)
```

It is working perfactly

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uh2Ep.png)

Answer (score -1):

Try this :

```
import math
import random
import word2number 
n = int(input("Please enter a number:"))
b = int(input("Please enter a number:"))
word = input('Please enter a word:')
range_amount = n*b

for number_of_words in range(random.randint(0,range_amount)):
    print(word)
```

Output :

```
Please enter a number:5
Please enter a number:2
Please enter a word:hello
hello
hello
hello
```